# Dynamic Linq - Methods on type 'Int32?' are not accessible

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am facing a problem since last three days and couldn't find a solution on google and stackoverflow.

I have a nullable int property in my model. When I try applying any function on that column using dynamic where clause, I am facing an error - "Methods on type 'Int32?' are not accessible".

Supposingly, my model structure is -

```
public class MyTestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to have a search query which is being created dynamically from front end. For example -

```
Where("Name.StartsWith(\"t\") and ParentId.ToString().StartsWith(\"1\") ");
```

My solution has catered all other types, but nullable types are not working here. I have also tried checking for null as well, but doesn't work. (Read this from some other forum):

```
Where("Name.StartsWith(\"t\") and (ParentId != null and ParentId.ToString().StartsWith(\"1\")) ");

Where("Name.StartsWith(\"t\") and (ParentId != null and ((int?)ParentId).ToString().StartsWith(\"1\")) ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ParentId.Value.ToString().StartsWith(\"1\")`. You don't need to check for `null` values if the query will be executed on an SQL server, because there is no NULL exceptions in SQL. If the query will be executed "locally" (against a .NET collection) you have to check for `null` values.

Comment: I thought you can't use ToString if it is Linq to Entites, you have to use SqlFunctions.StringConvert but I don't think you can call that in dynamic linq. Or have newer versions of EF added ToString support?

Comment: @Mant101 He hasn't specified if he is using EF or Linq-to-Sql. Linq-to-Sql supports the `.ToString()` (just checked)

Comment: ParentId.Value.ToString() worked for me. Thanks.

Can you explain the logic behind this? or any help article which talks about it?